# I tried to set Konsole to run from shell (or something) Now it won't open unless from root

Tags: terminal, linux-mint

I have Linux Mint 14.  I was advised to change my Konsole setting, and I must have done it wrong.  I tried to change Profile->General->Command from /lib/bash/ to something else.  Now when I try to launch it from the GUI it closes right away.  I can launch it as root and su to myself.  When I try to launch from there I get:

```
joe@Mint ~/Documents/workspace/archive $ konsole
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave
```

Is anybody familiar with this problem and its solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message has nothing to do with your problem. It is because you are running a KDE app and you are not (I guess) using KDE. Your problem is the setting you changed. You have set `konsole`'s SHELL to something that is not a shell, to fix it, you will need to edit a configuration file. If you have not changed the name of your default profile, that file should be `$HOME/.kde/share/apps/konsole/Shell.profile`.

So, open that file in a text editor (for example, gedit):

```
gedit ~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/Shell.profile
```

In that file, you will find these lines:

```
[General]
Command=/bin/WHATEVER_YOU_SET_IT_TO
```

What you need to do is change `/bin/WHATEVER_YOU_SET_IT_TO` to point to `/bin/bash` again. Then save the file and try to open `konsole` again.

Comment: No luck, in fact the file you sent me to was blank.

Comment: In that case, you have probably changed the profile name. Could you post the output of `ls $HOME/.kde/share/apps/konsole/` please?

Comment: Thanks @terdon.  I found the settings file under a different name.  All set.